# Тест на проникновение (пентест)

Tags: безопасность, тестирование

Я представляю перечень необходимого материала, который стоит пропустить через себя, чтобы вникнуть в такую штуку, как пентест (не путать со скрипт кид), но все же не подскажете направление, в котором стоит копать, литературу, можно на английском, почитать?.. Для начала я решил поднять свой уровень кодинга, но все-таки ощущение, что что-то не то делаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Направление: почитайте про [фаззинг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) (тестирование систем посредством передачи им не ожидаемых аргументов).